# Is this (1.11716..) a known/named constant?

Tags: geometry, constants

While looking at the Wikipedia entry for the Supergolden ratio  *aka*  Narayana's cow constant (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergolden_ratio), I noticed the following construction involving that constant and a 120-degree ($2\pi/3$ radian) triangle on that page:

[image: 120 degree triangle]

I then began to wonder about similar constructions with other fractional angles: $2\pi/2$, $2\pi/4$, ...

I found that an angle of $2\pi/2$ gives a degenerate triangle based on the golden ratio:

[image]

$2\pi/4$ gives a right triangle based on the square-root of the golden ratio:

[image]

And $2\pi/6$ gives an equilateral triangle based on unity:

[image]

Nothing too surprising or new in the results so far, but an angle of $2\pi/5$ (72-degrees) produced the following:

[image]

So, the positive solution to $-2 - x + \sqrt 5 x - 2 x^2 + 2 x^4=0$, approximate value $1.11716..$, minimal polynomial $1
 + x + x^2 + x^3 - x^4 - x^5 - 2 x^6 + x^8$

Is this a known/named constant?

Comment: It is not a constant from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_constants), but this is only a small list...

Comment: The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.11715586807111&lookup_type=simple) doesn't have a match for the longer decimal expansion, $1.11715586807111\ldots$.

Comment: I was getting around to this question myself.  Pi/4  is related to the square root of $1 - x^2 - 2 x^3 + x^4=0$.  I can also relate Pi/3 to the square root of the root for $1 - x - x^2 - 2 x^3 + x^4=0$.

Comment: The polynomial is known.  http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/8.4.42903125.1

Comment: The polynomials involved for Pi/7 and Pi/9 are not known at lmfdb.org.